# Youtube responds super slowly

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, youtube

I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome on Windows 8.1, and Youtube is really slow to react to mouse commands. When I mouse over anything it takes almost a full second to respond. Same with clicking and scrolling. When I first open the page, it runs just fine, no lag at all, but it only lasts for a few seconds.

I can provide more details if needed.

*Kind and constructive responses are greatly appreciated!*

Answer (score 1):

You should check your computer's resource utilization to narrow down what is causing the problem. You can open Task Manager by right-clicking the taskbar (in the black space down at the bottom where your running application icons are) and selecting it from the list. Click "More Details" in the lower left corner to expand the window. From here, you can select the Performance tab to see how your computer's resources are being utilized. You should check CPU and Memory to see how heavily they are being utilized when you experience the slow-downs.

If they aren't heavily utilized (say, <70%), you can check the Chrome Task Manager to see what is consuming all your resources. You can open this using Shift-Esc key combination while inside Chrome. Then click the CPU header to sort by utilization and see what is consuming the largest shares of the processor.

Possible culprits could be:

- Extensions in Google Chrome

  - Ad blockers
  - Things that add buttons/change page style (share tools)
- Video drivers

  - Sometimes video drivers combined with Chrome's hardware acceleration being on or off can cause issues. Try updating to the latest graphics drivers. If that doesn't help, try toggling hardware acceleration see: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/enable-hardware-acceleration-in-chrome.html

You didn't mention, but if this is a laptop, make sure "High Performance" mode is enabled. You can right-click on the battery logo in the system tray (button right) and select "Power options" to check. Sometimes power saving settings will limit your computer's performance which could also be causing issues.

If you're at a loss after all this, try using another browser. If you're experiencing issues with that too, you should start investigating your computer such as hardware and whether you have security software that could be slowing things down (such as McAfee, Norton, etc)

Comment: CPU never went beyond 20%, and I have more RAM than I've ever used up. Chrome's task manager said that I was using even less of the CPU than 20%. I tried disabling all of the extensions that would do anything to Youtube and nothing helped there either, but running in another browser (in my case Chrome with someone else's profile as well as the dreaded Internet Explorer) didn't have any problems, so my issue is probably caused by the extensions. Hardware acceleration didn't make a difference either. I'll continue troubleshooting when I get more time.